# Why I cannot see any vectors in ListVectorPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, vector

I have a couple of vectors. However, they are not ordered in a regular 3D fashion. Nevertheless, regarding the manual **"With the setting VectorPoints->All, ListVectorPlot3D instead shows vectors associated with the particular vector field data points given."** So I guess MMA should be able to display the following example:

```
vectors = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 0}, {3, 1, 1}};
points = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};
combo = Transpose[{points, vectors}];

ListVectorPlot3D[combo, VectorPoints -> points]
```

But plotting this, results in an empty box. Any hints?

EDIT: The data above are showing a MWE. I have in mind to plot in total 5000 vectors...

Comment: Not really. As far as I understand, `Arrow` affords starting and ending point of the vector. I have a direction (here as _vectors_) and the center position of the vectors (here as _points_).

Comment: Right, my mistake, like: `Graphics3D[Arrow[{#, +##} & @@@ combo]]`?

Comment: Yeah, this is somehow what I want. Why isn´t `ListVectorPlot3D` able to show that? In addition to your above answer: How can I code the color of the arrows, for example linked with the `Norm` of the vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands that start with "List" usually expect data to lie on a regular grid... I think the solution suggested in the comment by Kuba is great. Usually, I do it with

```
s = 0.1;
Graphics3D[Arrow[Transpose[{points, points + s vectors}]]]
```

where `s` is a scaling parameter.